# Grab matching column from text file in python list

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, delimiter

I have a text file that look like :
(from ipython )
cat path_to_file

```
0   0.25    truth fact 
1   0.25    train home find travel
........
199 0.25    video box store office
```

I have another list

```
vec = [(76, 0.04334748761500331),
 (128, 0.03697806086341099),
 (81, 0.03131634819532892),
 (1, 0.03131634819532892)]
```

Now i want to only grab the matching first column from vec with first column of text file and show 1,2nd columns of vec with 3rd column from text file as my output.

If i had text file in same format as vec, i could have used set(a) & set(b).
But values in test file are tabbed spaced(that's what it looks like when doing following)

with open( path_to_file ) as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

Output is :

```
['0\t0.25\ttruth fact lie
.........................
 '198\t0.25\tfan genre bit enjoy ',
 '199\t0.25\tvideo box store office  ']
```

Comment: You can specify the delimiter to use with `split`, e.g. `split("\t")` and then compare the first element with your vec

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NumPy:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rfn

dtype = [('index', int), ('text', object)]
table = np.loadtxt(path_to_file, dtype=dtype, usecols=(0,2), delimiter='\t')

dtype = [('index', int), ('score', float)]
array = np.array(vec, dtype=dtype)

joined = rfn.join_by('index', table, array)

for row in joined:
      print row['index'], row['score'], row['text']
```

If you care a lot about performance you can use `np.savetxt()` to do the output too, but I thought it was easier to understand this way.

Comment: Worked! Is it possible to keep the original vec order. with above code, output is sorted in asc order of first column.

Comment: Sure, try `order = np.searchsorted(table['index'], array['index'])` and then `for row in joined[order]`.  This assumes the input file is sorted.

Comment: Did you mean like this:
`order = np.searchsorted(table['index'], array['index']) and then

for row in joined[order]:
 print row['index'], row['score'], row['text']
IndexError: index 76 is out of bounds for size 10`

Comment: Yeah, I sort of assumed you didn't have any elements that weren't in both vec and the file.  You may need to work on some tweaks to my code to make it exactly suit your complete inputs.

Comment: i got the sorting working as well :)
`joined = sorted(joined, key=itemgetter(2), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Converting vec to a `dict` and splitting the lines using `"\t"` as the delimiter should work:

```
vecdict = dict(vec)

output = []
for l in open('path_to_file'):
    words = l.split('\t')
    key = float(words[0])
    if vecdict.has_key(key):
        output.append("%s %f %s"%(words[0], vecdict[key], ' '.join(words[2:])) )
```

`output` should then be a list of strings.

PS: If you have multiple delimiters or are not sure which it is you could either use repeated calls to `split`, or `re`, e.g.

```
print re.findall("[\w]+", "this has    multiple delimiters\tHere")

>> ["this", "has", "multiple", "delimiters", "Here"]
```

Comment: Thanks. that worked but output is a single string without any space between values: ['90.0256546355272dark light\n']. i'm trying to get values as seperate as 90 0.25 string. Also , this dict function automatically sorts the vec. is their way to keep the list unsorted in dict.

Comment: Did you use my edited version (I updated the code ~6 mins ago to include a space between 1st and 2nd field)

Comment: yes, that worked. i added one more space.   
`output.append(words[0] + ' ' +str(vecdict[key]) + ' ' +' '.join(words[2:]) )`

Comment: Yeah spotted that just now too - switched to using string formatting (see last update) to remove the cludgy string concatenation.